# rotating xticks in seaborn scatterplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization

i have an aggregate dataset that i am trying to visualise, it looks like that:

[image]

and i need to plot some statistics for 18 states. currently the plot looks in the following way:

[image]

and i manage to set xticks with the following code, however there is no rotate and i get an error. the code for the plot is:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (15, 6))
sns.scatterplot(ax = ax, x = 'state', y = 'price per acre, usd', data = data)
ax.set_xlabel("state", size = 12)
ax.set_ylabel('average price per acre of land, usd', size = 12)
ax.set_title('average prices on industrial land', size = 20)
ax.set_xticklabels(data['state'], rotation = 45)
plt.show()
```

and the error i get looks like this:

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:
-> 3363                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3364 
   3365         if is_scalar(key) and isna(key) and not self.hasnans:

KeyError: 'state'
```

so how i can rotate those labels (with names of states in the plot so that i do not receive an error and got a visually nice plot)? the column with the names of the state is called "state" as it is clearly from the plot code

Comment: What is the output of `print(data.columns)` inserted right before `ax.set_xticklabels`?

Comment: it's  ```Index(['price', 'square, ac', 'price per acre, usd'], dtype='object')```

Comment: so where is your `state` column here?

Comment: i do not know, probably it is not here because it is the index, as this dataframe was received after groupping the bigger dataframe by state. i will now edit the question and insert the table that i am trying to plot. and anyway the plot did insert state names from somewhere in the x-axis labels

Comment: `state` is now the index, what if you do `ax.set_xticklabels(data.index, rotation = 45)`?

Comment: yes, it helped! thank you so much! only starting with sns/mpl

Comment: you're welcome! BTW, sns put the state names on the x axis as you had a **named** index with the name `state`, so you plotted over the index, not over the column `state`.

Comment: Is the data type of the y-axis a string? If the last column is the y-axis in the data presented, the data is displayed in descending order starting with Florida and at the same time the state names are rotated.

Comment: no, the data type of y-axis (average price per acre, usd) is an integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the tick parameters, e.g. the rotation, use [`set_tick_params`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_tick_params.html) instead of re-setting the labels along with the rotation:

```
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(rotation = 45)
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks to [stef](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3944322/stef) we found out that the name of the column i was trying to use was actually an index, so i've modified the line to look for those state names in the index and it worked:

```
ax.set_xticklabels(data.index, rotation = 45)
```

Comment: please see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72773231/3944322) for a better way to do it.